# docker-credential-ecr-login not installed or not available in PATH (Dockerfile not building with docker-compose)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am having a hard time building this dockerfile in docker-compose.
I am following this example here [watchtower private-registries](https://containrrr.dev/watchtower/private-registries/)
The Dockerfile works just fine when I use `docker build`.
I also don't have a lot of experience with Docker but I have exhausted my capabilities.
The error I keep getting on `docker-compose` is:

```
docker.credentials.errors.InitializationError: docker-credential-ecr-login not installed or not available in PATH
[12939] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Below is the working Dockerfile.

```
FROM golang:latest

ENV GOPATH /go
ENV PATH $PATH:$GOPATH/bin

ENV CGO_ENABLED 0
ENV REPO github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper/ecr-login/cli/docker-credential-ecr-login

RUN go get -u $REPO

RUN rm /go/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login

RUN go build \
  -o /go/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login \
  /go/src/$REPO

WORKDIR /go/bin/
```

This is my attempt at docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  helper:
    build: .
    image: helper:latest
    container_name: helper
   
    volumes:
      - $HOME/.docker/config.json:/config.json
      - ./go/bin:/go/bin
    environment:
      - HOME=/
      - PATH=$PATH:/go/bin
      - REPO=github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper/ecr-login/cli/docker-credential-ecr-login
      
volumes:
  helper: {}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try deleting (after backup) the `~/.docker/config.json` file and try again? Also please tell us your platform.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu machine. I will try that in about 2 hours

Comment: @AliTou, that works. Please explain to me what is going on. I will still need config.json to finish this.

Comment: What was the contents of this file? Apparently, the options you provided in this file were not suitable for docker-compose. Either you had some extra configurations which you didn't have the required binaries, or you lacked some options to let docker-compose work. I got the idea from this comment: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/7495#issuecomment-642915975

Answer (score 1):

The documentation was not very clear on this issue.
The solution was to install `docker-credential-ecr-login` on my local machine first before using `docker-compose`.
Refer to [amazon-ecr-credential-helper](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper) installation.
`go get -u github.com/awslabs/amazon-ecr-credential-helper/ecr-login/cli/docker-credential-ecr-login`